# Static deployment on Jetty

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, hotdeploy

How can I configure jetty to deploy only one specific web application, and disable hot deployment (disable monitoring webapps directory, disable checking this single application for changes) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the context provider only, and just disable the webapp provider.  Then you have no scanning of the webapps directory, just a context file that points to your webapp.

edit the start.ini file and make sure you have the jetty-deploy.xml and jetty-contexts.xml files active, and comment out the jetty-webapps.xml line.  Then you just need a file in the contexts directory that points to your webapp.

more on the context provider here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/ContextDeployer

Comment: Thank you! I see in jetty-deploy.xml 
<Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>

Can I disable scanning (i.e. it will use only contexts existing on startup) ?

Comment: set it to 0 to disable scanning after the initial scan

Comment: same would work for the webapp provider, however I like the control the context provider gives in general

Comment: Thank you, what is the difference in control?

Comment: you can configure contexts, tweak classloading, setup authentication services, choose where the war unpacks, etc etc...things like that

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right then it means you want to to embed jetty in your application as compared to deploy your web application in jetty.

If that is the case the read this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty else tell me exactly what you are stuck with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what Pavel meant. He says "disable monitoring webapps directory", which implies that there is a webapps directory, which implies that this is not an embedded deployment.

Comment: No, I want to run standalone jetty, but w/o hot deployment